# how to filter an array of an array in angular 7

Tags: angular

hello i need your help to solve a problem,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me tell you some basic rules:

- avoid let and use const where possible
- use `includes()` instead of `indexOf() !== -1`
- try to extract complex predicates
- Please type

Personal additional suggestion:

- Avoid the ||. For me it is harder to read then simple checking one
  condition by another. Also you can add quite easy log outputs for
  example.

As a result you achieve something like this

```
public filterList = (value: string) => {

    if (this.virtualServersInitialList) {
        const virtualServers: Vs[] = this.virtualServersInitialList.filter(vs => searchVs(vs, value));
    }
}

public function searchVs(vs: Vs, value: string): boolean {
    // search vs name
    if (vs.vs.tmName.split("/")[2].toLowerCase().includes(value)) {
        return true;
    }

    // search destination
    if (vs.vs.destination.toLowerCase().includes(value)) {
        return true;
    }

    // search pool name
    if (vs.vs.pools.some((pool: Pool) => pool.tmName.split("/")[2].toLowerCase().includes(value))) {
        return true;
    }

    // search addr & port
    // TODO by you
}
```

Comment: he doesn't work for me my questions it how to filter addr and port ????